# Android Unit Testing with Missed Private Method in Jacoco Code Coverage Report

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, code-coverage, jacoco

Hi guys!

I don't have experience in testing but am trying to do it for my current Android practice project.

I have been researching and reading about unit testing on private methods, where people would say we should not be testing them as they are implementations instead of behaviour.

However, by using Jacoco to generate the code coverage report, it would state that certain private method or member variable assignment.

My question is, should I re-write my methods, or should I ignore the report. Or there are other ways to test them.

Thank you.

Screenshot and code:

[image]

```
public class HNStoriesPresenter<V> implements GetHackerNewsContract.StoriesPresenter {    

private static final String TAG = "HNStoriesPresenter";
private GetHackerNewsContract.StoriesView view;
private HackerNewsAPI apiService;
private CompositeDisposable disposables;

private List<HackerNewsStory> hackerNewsStoryList;
private String[] topStoriesID;

// range [0-topStoriesID.length)
private int numStoriesLoaded = 0;

public HNStoriesPresenter(HackerNewsAPI apiService) {
    this.apiService = apiService;
    disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
    hackerNewsStoryList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void setView(V view){
    this.view = (GetHackerNewsContract.StoriesView) view;
    this.loadTopStories();
}

@Override
public void loadTopStories() {
    // Reset this variable to load stories from start (first page)
    numStoriesLoaded = 0;
    hackerNewsStoryList.clear();

    apiService.getTopStories()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(storiesID -> {
                    topStoriesID = storiesID;
                    pullStories();
                },
                error -> view.onFecthStoriesError());
}

@Override
public void loadMoreStories() {
    pullStories();
}

// Function to load NUMBER_OF_STORIES_TO_DISPLAY individual story item
private void pullStories() {
    // Remove previous stories
    hackerNewsStoryList.clear();
    //((GetHackerNewsContract.StoriesView) view).clearStories();

    // Counter to limit total stories to load
    int currentLoaded = 0;
    int start = numStoriesLoaded;
    List<String> storiesToPullList = new ArrayList<>();

    while (numStoriesLoaded < topStoriesID.length && currentLoaded < NUMBER_OF_STORIES_TO_DISPLAY) {
        // Get story item from server
        storiesToPullList.add(topStoriesID[numStoriesLoaded]);
        numStoriesLoaded++;
        currentLoaded++;
    }

    // Use flatMap to ensure the order of items received
    // is same as the list (synchronized).

    // This makes the API call visibly slow. There could
    // be better way but stick with this method for now.
    Single<List<HackerNewsStory>> storiesObservable = Observable.fromIterable(storiesToPullList)
            .flatMap(id -> apiService.getStory(id)).toList();

    storiesObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(loadStoriesHandler,
                    error -> view.onFecthStoriesError()
            );

                    //HNStoriesPresenter.this.loadStoriesHandler, HNStoriesPresenter.this.singleErrorHandler);
}

private Consumer<List<HackerNewsStory>> loadStoriesHandler = new Consumer<List<HackerNewsStory>>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(List<HackerNewsStory> hackerNewsStories) throws Exception {
        hackerNewsStoryList.clear();
        hackerNewsStoryList.addAll(hackerNewsStories);

        if (hackerNewsStoryList.size() > 0)
            view.onFetchStoriesSuccess(hackerNewsStoryList);
        else
            view.onFecthStoriesError();

        if (numStoriesLoaded < topStoriesID.length)
            view.showLoadMore();
        else
            view.hideLoadMore();
    }
};
}
```